# A quart to much oil in my Toyota 4 runner 2001

Tags: oil

I put a quart to much oil in my Toyota 4 runner 2001. Then I went for a road trip! I noticed oil coming out the back of my car! And now I am hearing a noise! Ut oh!! Did I ruin my engine?

Comment: Coming out of the back of the car where?  Like drips on the road or what?

Comment: Agreed @jphi1618

Answer (score 0):

Actual Oil, out of the exhaust pipe ?  If the oil has gone though the intake manifold (re-breather route) you run the risk of seizing or stalling as the piston tries to compress it, but before that it will run very smoky and rough.
The overfill risk is normally from whipping the oil, so that it foams and even possibly emulsifies, rendering it hard to pump and effectively deliver.

Work out where the oil is coming from first. Then work out where the noise is coming from, and the nature of the noise. If the engine seized, even momentarily you have possibilities:

1. You've pulled a big end and it is stretched, you may "throw a rod" soon.
2. You have piston/connecting rod damage.

Get someone to listen to it, and drain some oil if you have not already.

It may not be that bad, Toyotas will take a bit of abuse, but it sounds like you put in "a lot" of oil.